# add time in loading web service in windows phone

Tags: json, web-services, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

This is my code to load web service in my app:

```
public LoadData() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    PostData(); 
} 

private void PostData() 
{ 
    Uri uri = new Uri("my web service url"); 
    WebClient client= new WebClient(); 
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
    client.UploadStringAsync(uri); 
    client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadComplete; 
} 

public void client_UploadComplete(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   var test= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(e.Result); 
}
```

At this point if web service takes more than 10 seconds to load all the data in variable test, then a message box or a popup box open which say " Slow Connection Please retry" along with retry button which again load my `PostData();`
how would be possible to add time in loading web service in WP
please help me on this.....

Answer (score 1):

Add a timer event and start it before your asynchronous upload. The event fires after 10 secs. But if the code reaches inside ur complete event disable the timer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you please post some sample code for this..it would be really helpful..

Comment: On a train.. Using a phone to type. The way you have added UploadStringCompleted event is the way to go. Create a timer object with the constructor taking 10 seconds as parameter using Timer class somewhere else in this class. Then start it just before the upload and have a ppopup when this gets fired. Add code to disable in the uploadComplete method.If the uploadcomplete gets fired the timer gets disabled.

Comment: thanks again for this I'll try this using  DispatcherTimer & and get back on this...